# How CKEDITOR first line indent paragraph?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

How can I do the first line indentation in Ckeditor like ms word? As far as I know, there is no plugin for it.
Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about the view mode, then just edit `contents.css` and put at the end:

```
p {
    text-indent: 40px;
}
```

or whatever length you like.

However, this will not appear in source code, so if you want your data to be displayed with that indentation **inline** somewhere else other than CKEditor,you could replace the `<p>` tag prior to submission like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<p>/gi, '<p style="text-indent: 40px;"')
```

When you load your data again, the `style` attribute of the `<p>` tags will be deleted due to the [Advanced Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf), but you will still see the effect in view mode because of the change you made to `contents.css`